# how to find xcode 7.2 .app file location on the mac

Tags: xcode

I have project in Xcode 7.2 and i need .app file it generates to be able to point it to monkey talk scripts to run test.

i could not find any options to see it.

i was looking in `~/Library/` locations etc.

but no results. is there a way to find build location etc in the Xcode 7.2

The monkey talk target only accepts the .app file

or if there is a way to run mt scripts directly from the installed location on simulator that will  help too.

Answer (score 1):

In Xcode if you click on **Window -> Organizer** you will se a list of build archives. You can right click on then (if there is any of course) and click on **Show in Finder**. That will be the location of the **.xcarchive** that contains inside it the dsyms, plists and the **.app** which I suppose is what you are looking for. In order to archive a build you have to click on **Product -> Archive**. I hope that helps.

The full path on my machine is **/Library/Developer/Xcode/Archives/<#date#>/<#project#>.xcarchive/Products/Application/<#Application#>.app**